# Who uses GnuSTEP?

Tags: linux, gui, objective-c, frameworks

This has been a big question lurking at the back of my head. From what I see, GnuSTEP nowadays is primarily a "hobby" project of a small but tightly-knit group of people. However I haven't seen a large commercial (off-the-shelf) application that uses it, apart from the small applications that comes with the GnuSTEP distribution.

Heck, since even Ubuntu doesn't really use it then is GnuSTEP really more than being a "hobby" framework?

I know that Sony's SNAP at one brief moment uses GnuSTEP, but they killed the platform before it can do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a list of [corporate developers and users](http://www.gnustep.org/developers/whoiswho.html). I'm at the inception of a project using GNUstep. I also still work with the people at Brainstorm (see the list), and used to work there myself: they employ some of the GNUstep project maintainers and their technology stack is based on it. However that's not a COTS package.

[TestPlant's](http://www.testplant.com) product, EggPlant is a cross-platform Objective-C product based on GNUstep. They document that in their [press release](http://www.testplant.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=30)(PDF).

Comment: What commercial product did any of those listed companies release that's based on GNUStep? Just because they are using Objective C doesn't make it GNUStep. I can't find any information on those listed companies website where it mentions GNUStep. May be the guys running them are the maintainers of GNUStep or something?

Comment: Here, for example: http://www.testplant.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=30

Comment: Alright. Agreed :D

Comment: From GnuSTEP's list of developers/users, I couldn't find any application that individuals can buy at an affordable price (say, < $1000 per license). Also it sounds like that list of clientele is mostly "legacy" users of the NextSTEP days (having legacy code when NextSTEP was popular in corporates).

Comment: @adib: strange thing about Free Software, that they're not focussed on commercial applications…anyway, you've seen that there are companies that depend on it financially, for whom it's not a hobby. What does it matter whether they produced off-the-shelf products or other things?

Comment: @GrahamLee It matters when you're selecting a framework for developing indie applications. Your last comment sounds like it answers why indies choose to go with Cocotron instead.

Answer (score 2):

There's [Étoilé](http://etoileos.com/), a project trying to make a desktop environment based on GnuSTEP, but it seems to be far from anything usable yet.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and what it's good for? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange